# Getting error when running the emulator in eclipse for target 15?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

Whenever I start the emulator or directly run a app on emulator, it just display the emulator and home screen never comes .In console I am getting this:

```
     emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
     [2012-08-09 11:20:42 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
     [2012-08-09 11:20:42 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
     [2012-08-09 11:20:42 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
     [2012-08-09 11:20:42 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
     [2012-08-09 11:20:42 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
```

I have tried GPU emulation to yes and in command line in run configuration -

```
        -gpu on
```

But still it is not working .Please someone could help me ?

Comment: is it only on sdk version 15? all the others work?

Comment: Actually all are not working I just tried 14 it is also not working?
Is there something with Graphic acceleration..dont know plz help

Answer (score 0):

Edit your AVD GUI settings. Hardware Section, select New. Hit the "Property" Dropdown Select "GPU Emulation" then "OK" Change "Gpu Emulation" to "YES" with the dropdown in Hardware Section.

Save and try again

EDIT: it could also come from recent updates. Please update all your components again including all your plugins to the newest version. There might be an update for eclipse itself as well. then delete your emulators and recreate them.

Comment: My system doesnot supprt Virtualization ...Does that matters?

Comment: that shouldnt matter. please make sure that first all your software (eclipse, plugins, sdks) is up to date. i had the strangest issues after software updates before when i only updated partly.